# max-width of image not working in flexbox for IE 11 but works on google chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating a 2 by 2 grid layout using flexbox where the first column items are merged together as shown below:

[image]

This works in Google Chrome without a problem. The image can grow until the maximum remaining width allocated by the flexbox. However, it does not work in IE11. The image stretches its container box and I've been googling and trying different solutions to no avail. It seems like my case is a little different from other similar questions.

Here is what it looks like in IE:
[image]

Can you help me spot the problem? I've provided a plunker where you can try your solutions.

CSS:

```
        body {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .element {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .name {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex: 0 0 100px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        .detail-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex: 1 0 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .detail {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 0 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .detail img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .name, .detail {
            border: 1px solid;
            margin: 8px;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
            word-break: break-word;
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="element">
        <div class="name">name</div>
        <div class="detail-wrapper">
            <div class="detail">
                <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*y6C4nSvy2Woe0m7bWEn4BA.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="detail">
                <a href="#">url</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/q6Xme6ETvW20Gw57CIWQ?p=preview

Comment: did you try to set `display: block` to `img`  ?

Comment: It Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE browser has some issues with Flex. It is not able to calculate the values properly with flex.

(1) I suggest you replace **max-width** with **width** in **.detail img** class.

(2) I suggest you replace **flex: 1 0 0;** with **flex: 0 0 auto;** in **.detail** class.

Edit:-

Added img tag inside one extra div solved the issue as informed by @Xegara. It also worked with **max-width** For IE 11 browser.

Modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
          width: 100%;
        }
        
 .extra_div{
          width: 100%;
        }

        .element {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
  
        }
        
        .name {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex: 0 0 100px;  
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        
        .detail-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
           /*flex: 0 0 auto;*/
  
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .detail {
            display: flex;
            /*flex: 1 0 0;*/
            flex: 0 0 auto; /*-------------------------made change here */
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        .detail img {
            max-width: 100%;   /*-------------------------made change here */
        }
        
        .name, .detail {
            border: 1px solid;
            margin: 8px;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
            word-break: break-word;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="element">
        <div class="name">name</div>
        <div class="detail-wrapper">
            <div class="detail">
  <div class="extra_div">
                 <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*y6C4nSvy2Woe0m7bWEn4BA.png" />
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detail">
                <a href="#">url</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Setting the width does not seem to be an issue but if the image is smaller than the container, then I want it to be displayed in its original size. Setting the width to 100% will always make the image fit the container.

Comment: I enclosed the img inside another div container with width: 100% and it worked! You can modify your answer accordingly or propose a better solution if you have and i'll accept your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer as per your last comment. Thanks for your understanding.